# Get tooltip from number input using selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, tooltip

I need to get tooltip from standard element, for example:

```
<input class="some_class" type="number" value="0" name="some_name"/>
```

I have no attributes which set tooltip on this element like "title" or maybe "alt" or something else. Browser generates tootltips by itself and it is default feature. For example, if i will set text value to this input i will get tooltip "Please enter a number" in Firefox.

Question is how to get text of this tooltip from java code using Selenium?

I guess that i need to make MouseOver event over my input and tooltip will be shown. I can do it. But i can't understand how to get text of this showing tooltip from code. What XPath expression maybe should i write to get access to this tooltip? Or maybe there is some core method for these purposes?

Comment: you can set `title` as request attribute in java and get in jsp as `${title}`.

Comment: @Prashant, if i understand you clearly, i have no access to jsp source code of the page. I have only deployed website and I'm writing an automated selenium test that's why your approach will not help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Actions toolTip = new Actions(driver);
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_xpath"));
toolTip.clickAndHold(ele).perform(); 
String ToolTipText = ele.getText();
```

or

```
String ToolTipText = ele.getAttribute("title")
```

Comment: Thank's for answer but this is not working because getText gets inner text of element & input haas no "title" attribute

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cssSelector for the tooltip:

```
input::-webkit-validation-bubble-message
```

I found it here, maybe it helps you: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/05/17/cross-browser-styling-of-html5-forms-even-in-older-browsers/

Comment: I have tried it and it's not working. I think this is only for html5 forms.